# Should I use a queue table to sync SQL Server to .NET Core app?

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, ado.net

We're working on a desktop .NET Core application that syncs all data with an Azure SQL Server instance. For security reasons, the connection string points to a user with only SELECT, INSERT, and EXEC permissions on a custom schema. I'd like to use some framework to sync a `DataGridView` Control to a table `Client`, so that when other users update the `Client` table when the application is running, the DataGridView will automatically be updated with the new information.

Right now, I'm thinking that we could create a trigger in SQL Server that inserts into a table `Client_Update` with the timestamp of the update, `Client_ID` PK, and XML/JSON string of object. Then, SQL Server sends out a notification using Service Broker. This alerts the client app through `SqlDependency`, which executes a stored procedure that retrieves all the `Client_ID`s and performs a SELECT query on them to retrieve the `Client` objects. These objects can then be updated in the DataGridView.

Alternatively, we could use Service Broker itself to send a message to the client app that contains the `Client` object that was updated, but I'm not that familiar with Service Broker. Is there a better approach?

Comment: Have you looked at [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server)?

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was trying to build, really speeds up the first half of development.